open react native app on receive push notification without click on notification
I want to open react native app when the device gets a push notification.
I have used this code to open the app It works fine only on Android version less then 10. but it does not work on Android version higher then 10.
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "broadcast received for message");

    Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.theDocSuiteDriver");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
      launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
      context.startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}


this code works when sending push notifications. but not with higher Android 10 and not getting any warning or error

Have you tried my solution yet ?

There are more restrictions (starting with Android 10) on background processes (like BroadcastReceivers triggered by push notifications) launching activities. This is to prevent interrupting the user when he is doing something important. You can only show a Notification and the user can launch the Activity then manually by clicking on the Notification. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

1. You should display a notification instead of launch intent and on pendingIntent assign the activity.
Try below code :
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "broadcast received for message");

    Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.theDocSuiteDriver");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "your_channel_id")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                .setContentText("Notification Text")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}

2. Make sure notification channel set up for Android 8 and above.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = "Channel Name";
    String description = "Channel Description";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("your_channel_id", name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

3. POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission for Andorid 13 and above
<manifest ...>
    <!-- Required only if your app targets Android 13. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>

Following above points will solve your problem.
Helpful links to consider :

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

